# Why koala program won't open on ubuntu-gnome 15.10 ?

Tags: 15.10

I have downloaded koala from:

http://koala-app.com/

I ran **koala_2.0.4_amd64.deb** file. Program installed as expected but when I run it it doesn't open. It spins for few seconds and nothing happens. Is that problem with program installation file or perhaps it is a problem with 15.10 compatibility ? Anyone know how to make koala to open ?

Answer (score 3):

I found actual solution in on koala git-hub repo in Wiki tab in FAQ section ([Koala Wiki](https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki)). 
In case anyone would encounter similar issue this is what you have to do:

**Solution:**

32bit: `cd /lib/i386-linux-gnu/` or `cd /usr/lib/`

64bit: `cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or `cd /usr/lib64/`

`sudo ln -s libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0`

If the libudev file in linux-gnu directory is not found, please install libudev0 below:

libudev0 for 32bit
libudev0 for 64bit
Now, try run koala again.

PORBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: Please accept your answer as the accepted answer

Comment: On Ubuntu (actually Pop OS 20.04) I was unable to install the dependency with these instructions, but I was able to get Koala working after installing libconf-2-4 per the instructions on this page: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libgconf-2-4